# Preserving ipython's input prompt filtering in customized prompts

Tags: ipython, prompt

As described in [the manual](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#pasting-of-code-starting-with-python-or-ipython-prompts), ipython is smart enough to automatically strip the default prompt from pasted lines of code -- very handy. I have customized my prompt to my liking, which unfortunately seems to have broken this logic. Is it possible to adapt the pattern match logic in my startup files to reflect a customized prompt, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the latest IPython (1.0 or the development version), then yes, although it's not something that we particularly support (i.e. the API might change in the future). Define a regex which will match your prompts - like this one for classic Python prompts: `re.compile(r'^(>>> ?|\.\.\. ?)')`.

Then you'll need some code like this (not tested):

```py
from IPython.core.inputtransformer import CoroutineInputTransformer, _strip_prompts

@CoroutineInputTransformer.wrap
def my_prompt():
    prompt_re = re.compile(r'foo')
    return _strip_prompts(prompt_re)

ip = get_ipython()
ip.input_splitter.physical_line_transforms.insert(0, my_prompt())
ip.input_transformer_manager.physical_line_transforms.insert(0, my_prompt())
```

You can put that in a startup file (`IPYTHONDIR/profile_default/startup/prompts.py`) to have it run automatically when you start IPython.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using that IPython version once the distros give it to me. I'm using 0.12.1/0.13.2 right now, where inputtransformer isn't available, so I can't test it.

Comment: It might be possible in those versions, but it's much more fiddly. I reworked the input transformation system for 1.0